# How to configure telnet service for yocto image

Tags: yocto, telnet, busybox

telnet is necessary in order to maintain compatibility with older software in this case.  I'm working with the Yocto Rocko 2.4.2 distribution.  when I try to telnet to the board I'm getting the oh so detailed message "connection refused".

Using the method [here](http://bec-systems.com/site/1145/modifying-the-busybox-config-in-openembedded) and the options [here](https://yocto.yoctoproject.narkive.com/CtsbIcSX/related-to-telnetd) I modified the busybox configuration per suggestion.  When the board is booted up and logged in, if you execute: telnet, it spits out usage info and a quick directory check shows that telnet is installed to /usr/bin/telnet.  My guess is that the telnet client is installed but the telnet server is not running?

I need to get telnetd to start manually at least so I know it will work with an init script in place. The second reference link there suggests that 'telnetd will not be started automatically though...' and that there will need to be an init script. How can I start telnetd manually for testing?

```
systemctl enable telnetd
```

returns: Unit telnetd.service could not be found

**UPDATE**
telnetd in located in /usr/sbin/telnetd.  I was able to manually start the telnetd service for testing from there. After manually starting the service telnet login now works. looking into writing a systemd init script to auto start the telnetd service, so I suppose this issue is closed. unless anyone would like to offer up detailed telnet busybox configuration and setup steps as an answer to 'How to configure telnet service for yocto image'

**update**
Perhaps there is something more? I created a unit file that looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=auto start telnetd

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/telnetd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

on reboot, systemd indicates the process executed and succeeded:

```
systemctl status telnetd
.
.
.
Process: 466 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/telnetd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
.
.
.
```

The service is not running however.  netstat -l does not list it and telnet login fails.  Something I'm missing?

**last update...i think**

so following [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429259/how-start-telnet-with-systemctl-in-debian) post, I managed to get telnet.socket service to startup on reboot.

```
systemctl status telnet.socket
```

shows that it is running and listening on 23. Now however, when I try to remote in with telnet I'm getting

```
Connection closed by foreign host
```

Everything I've read so far has been talking about xinetd service (which I do not have...).  What is confusing is that, if I just navigate to /usr/sbin/ and execute telnetd, the server is up and running and I can telnet into the board, so I do not believe I'm missing any utilities or services (like the above mentioned xinetd), but something is still not being configured correctly. any ideas?